# Shopify unable to authorize api request made with WS

Tags: playframework-2.0, shopify

I have set up an API key for a Shopify site and was able to do a GET request request with the following code

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://75da...:2a1dd3...@mytest.myshopify.com/admin/products.json");

response = httpClient.execute(get);
```

The above is in a junit test and uses Apache httpcomponents client 4.2.3 and httpcomponents core 4.2.4

With the same parameters I tried using WS.url() but I get a response of 401 - Unauthorized with message in the body

> [API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)

The code I used in the junit test:

```
WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url("https://75da...:2a1dd3...@mytest.myshopify.com/admin/products.json");

Promise<Response> promise = requestHolder.get();
Response response = promise.get();
```

I'm using play 2.1.3.

So the difference is using apache vs WS, I'm thinking some configuration is required for the WS. Can anybody provide some insight?

Thanks

Comment: Try using wireshark to see if the request looks fishy?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I had to set the authentication when using WS, for example

```
WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url("https://mytest.myshopify.com/admin/products.json");     

requestHolder.setAuth("75da...", "2a1dd3...");
Promise<Response> promise = requestHolder.get();
```